# Return rows with Max Date from Multiple Tables

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to pull information from the last transaction date on a product serial number, regardless of the last location. Sales, Manufacturing and Inventory transactions all reside in different tables.

I think I have narrowed down my columns enough with nested CASE statements, but now I need to return the most recent row, with 'Serial Number' being the unique value.

```
[IV00101].[ITEMDESC] AS 'Item Description',
[IV00200].[SERLNMBR] AS 'Serial Number',
[IV00200].[LOCNCODE] AS 'Location Code',  
    CASE ISNULL(COALESCE([SOP30200].[CUSTNAME],[SOP10100].[CUSTNAME]),'')
    WHEN '' THEN CASE ISNULL([BM30400].[DATERECD],'')
        WHEN '' THEN CASE
            WHEN [IV30400].[IVDOCTYP] = 1 THEN 'Adjustment'
            WHEN [IV30400].[IVDOCTYP] = 2 THEN 'Variance'
            WHEN [IV30400].[IVDOCTYP] = 3 THEN 'Transfer'
            ELSE 'Other'
            END
        ELSE 'Assembly'
        END
    ELSE CASE
        WHEN [SOP30200].[SOPNUMBE] LIKE 'RTN%' THEN 'Return'
        ELSE 'Sale'
        END
    END AS 'Transaction Type',
COALESCE([SOP30200].[DOCDATE], [BM30400].[DATERECD],[IV30200].[DOCDATE]) AS 'Last Transaction Date',
[SOP10201].[SOPNUMBE] AS 'Document Number',
COALESCE([SOP30200].[CUSTNAME],[SOP10100].[CUSTNAME]) AS 'Bill To' ,
[SOP10106].[USERDEF2] AS 'End Client' from [IV00200]
 inner join [IV00101] on [IV00200].[ITEMNMBR] = [IV00101].[ITEMNMBR]
 left join [IV30400] on [IV00200].[SERLNMBR] = [IV30400].[SERLTNUM]
 left join [SOP10201] on [IV00200].[SERLNMBR] = [SOP10201].[SERLTNUM]
 left join [SOP30200] on [SOP10201].[SOPNUMBE] = [SOP30200].[SOPNUMBE]
 left join [IV30200] on [IV30400].[DOCNUMBR] = [IV30200].[DOCNUMBR]
 left join [BM30400] on [IV00200].[SERLNMBR] = [BM30400].[SERLTNUM]
 left join [SOP10106] on [SOP10201].[SOPNUMBE] = [SOP10106].[SOPNUMBE]
 left join [SOP10100] on [SOP10201].[SOPNUMBE] = [SOP10100].[SOPNUMBE]
```

Because of all my left joins, this is what I am getting:

```
Item A  Product Info    123456789   SITEID1 Adjustment  10/31/2018  120696  Customer A
Item A  Product Info    123456789   SITEID2 Transfer    11/20/2018  120696  Customer A
Item A  Product Info    123456789   SITEID2 Sale    3/25/2019   120696  Customer A
```

How do I group my rows so I only return this?

`Item A   Product Info    123456789   SITEID2 Sale    3/25/2019   120696  Customer A`

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()`

Comment: I tried inserting
```ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [IV00200].[SERLNMBR],[IV30200].[DOCDATE] ORDER BY (COALESCE([SOP30200].[DOCDATE], [BM30400].[DATERECD],[IV30200].[DOCDATE]))) AS Row,
```
in the first line, but when I tried to add MAX at the beginning of the clause, I got the error "Msg 4109, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Windowed functions cannot be used in the context of another windowed function or aggregate."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common table expression (CTE) plus the window function `ROW_NUMBER` should work.

1. Put your query into a CTE
2. Add `ROW_NUMBER`
3. Filter the CTE results by RowNum = 1 (to get the latest transaction)

```
WITH [SomeGoodName_CTE]
     AS (SELECT [IV00101].[ITEMDESC] AS 'Item Description'
              , [IV00200].[SERLNMBR] AS 'Serial Number'
              , [IV00200].[LOCNCODE] AS 'Location Code'
              , CASE ISNULL(COALESCE([SOP30200].[CUSTNAME], [SOP10100].[CUSTNAME]), '')
                  WHEN '' THEN CASE ISNULL([BM30400].[DATERECD], '')
                                 WHEN '' THEN CASE
                                                WHEN [IV30400].[IVDOCTYP] = 1 THEN 'Adjustment'
                                                WHEN [IV30400].[IVDOCTYP] = 2 THEN 'Variance'
                                                WHEN [IV30400].[IVDOCTYP] = 3 THEN 'Transfer'
                                                ELSE 'Other'
                                              END
                                 ELSE 'Assembly'
                               END
                  ELSE CASE
                         WHEN [SOP30200].[SOPNUMBE] LIKE 'RTN%' THEN 'Return'
                         ELSE 'Sale'
                       END
                END AS 'Transaction Type'
              , COALESCE([SOP30200].[DOCDATE], [BM30400].[DATERECD], [IV30200].[DOCDATE]) AS 'Last Transaction Date'
              , [SOP10201].[SOPNUMBE] AS 'Document Number'
              , COALESCE([SOP30200].[CUSTNAME], [SOP10100].[CUSTNAME]) AS 'Bill To'
              , [SOP10106].[USERDEF2] AS 'End Client'
              , [RowNum] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [IV00200].[ITEMNMBR] ORDER BY COALESCE([SOP30200].[DOCDATE], [BM30400].[DATERECD], [IV30200].[DOCDATE]) DESC)
         FROM [IV00200]
              INNER JOIN [IV00101]
                ON [IV00200].[ITEMNMBR] = [IV00101].[ITEMNMBR]
              LEFT JOIN [IV30400]
                ON [IV00200].[SERLNMBR] = [IV30400].[SERLTNUM]
              LEFT JOIN [SOP10201]
                ON [IV00200].[SERLNMBR] = [SOP10201].[SERLTNUM]
              LEFT JOIN [SOP30200]
                ON [SOP10201].[SOPNUMBE] = [SOP30200].[SOPNUMBE]
              LEFT JOIN [IV30200]
                ON [IV30400].[DOCNUMBR] = [IV30200].[DOCNUMBR]
              LEFT JOIN [BM30400]
                ON [IV00200].[SERLNMBR] = [BM30400].[SERLTNUM]
              LEFT JOIN [SOP10106]
                ON [SOP10201].[SOPNUMBE] = [SOP10106].[SOPNUMBE]
              LEFT JOIN [SOP10100]
                ON [SOP10201].[SOPNUMBE] = [SOP10100].[SOPNUMBE])
     SELECT *
     FROM [SomeGoodName_CTE]
     WHERE [RowNum] = 1;
```